# Many to many relationships MongoDB mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema and users can be friends.

I have a friendship schema:

```
var friendshipSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    from : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    to : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

Now, I want to get all friends from an user `foo`:

```
Friendship
.find({
    $or : [
        { from : foo._id },
        { to : foo._id }
    ]
})
```

The problem is: I want to populate all friends from `foo`, but not `foo` himself (since for X friends I would have X `foo`s populated).

How could I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
Friendship
.find({
    $or : [
        { from : user._id },
        { to : user._id }
    ]
})
.populate({
    path: 'from',
    match: { _id: { $ne: user._id }},
    select: '-token'
},{
    path: 'to',
    match: { _id: { $ne: user._id }},
    select: '-token'
})
.lean()
.exec(function(err, retData)
{
         // Do something here...
});
```